# vscode-go: any code using cgo does not show suggestions when using the Go and ClangD extensions

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, clangd, gopls

My understanding is the Go extension for vscode calls the relevant C extension when completing cgo code. When I use the Microsoft C/C++ extension, the cgo completions seem to work. However, I prefer the ClangD extension, but the combination of ClangD and gopls gives no cgo completions.

Is this expected, or did I screw up the config? The two language servers seem to be working fine until it’s time to deal with cgo. Also, all code compiles fine from my console.

Comment: Re: "My understanding is the Go extension for vscode calls the relevant C extension when completing cgo code", is there some documentation or other resource that your understanding is based on, and if so, could you link to it please?